# Proving $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\mu (n)}n=0$ where $\mu$ is the Möbius function

Tags: sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory, mobius-function

> How to prove that Dirichlet series $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\mu (n)}{n^s}$$ converges to $0$ at $s=1$, where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function?

I know it is equal to reciprocal of Riemann zeta function $\frac{1}{\zeta (s)}$ and can be also represented by Euler product $\prod _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(1-p_n^{-s}\right)$, but the product is called divergent if its value goes to 0 and none of its factors is equal to zero, so I think this product will not help me.

Comment: This is a delicate result, comparable in difficulty to the Prime Number Theorem.

Comment: I suspect that you are currently going through a proof of the Prime Number Theorem. This is a step in most analytic proofs of the theorem.

Comment: So there is no proof that would have reasonable length to write it here?

Comment: The steps in the proof are exactly the same as [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2433537/276986) and are explained in details in every analytic number theory books. See also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Proof_sketch). What we can show in a few lines is that $|\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(n)}{n}| \le 1$

Comment: To obtain $|\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(n)}{n}| \le 1$ start from $\sum_{n \le x} \mu(n) \lfloor x/n \rfloor$

Comment: @reuns If I can show that $|\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(n)}{n}| \le 1$ then I am done, no? It would mean the sum is convergent and only possible value that makes a pole for zeta function at s=1 is 0. (if I take that zeta has a pole at s=1 as a fact).

Comment: Oh, no! It could also oscillate forever somewhere between -1 and 1. I would have to eliminate also this possibility.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-1-it} = \zeta(1+it)+\frac{N^{-it}}{-it}+\mathcal{O}(N^{-1})$ oscillates this way. And it would be the case for $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(n)}{n}$ if $\zeta$ had some zeros on $\Re(s) = 1$

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to see that
\[\lim_{s \searrow 1} \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} = 0,\]
because the left-hand side is equal to $1/\zeta(s)$ for $\Re(s) > 1$, and $\zeta(s)$ has a pole at $s = 1$. However, the fact that this limit is equal to $0$ does *not* imply that
\[\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} = o(1).\]
This is much harder to prove, as has been noted in the comments; you need to additionally know that $\zeta(s)$ is nonvanishing on the line $\Re(s) = 1$.

There are several approaches to prove this result. One can prove this via Perron's inversion formula to show that this is equal to
\[\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\sigma - i\infty}^{\sigma + i\infty} \frac{1}{\zeta(s + 1)} \frac{x^s}{s} \, ds\]
for $\sigma > 0$, then move the contour to the line $\sigma = - c/\log x$ for some $c > 0$ and use the highly nontrivial fact that $\zeta(s)$ has a zero-free region, in which one can bound it from below.

Another approach is to show that $\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} = o(1)$ is *equivalent* to the bound $\psi(x) \sim x$, where $\psi(x) = \sum_{p^k \leq x} \log p$. This can be done via "elementary methods" in about half a page of work. Of course, the statement that $\psi(x) \sim x$ is equivalent to the prime number theorem via partial summation.

Comment: I do not agree it is easy to see. If you take for granted that zeta has a pole at s=1 and that the series converge at s=1 only then it is easy to see that the sum must converge to 0. If you do not have for granted that the series converges then there is still possibility that the series could diverge at s=1 even though the zeta has a pole at s=1.

Comment: @azerbajdzan, my first sentence says nothing about the convergence of the series at $s = 1$! Rather, it is saying that the function $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$, a function of the variable $s$ that is well-defined as an absolutely convergent series $\Re(s) > 1$, converges to zero as $s$ tends to $1$.

Comment: In particular, I agree with you that it is highly nontrivial that $\lim_{s \searrow 1} \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n}$; the latter sum isn't absolutely convergent, and it takes work (and is equivalent to the prime number theorem) to show that it is conditionally convergent.