# The partial sum $\sum_{n \le N} \mu(n)/n \ne 0$ for finite $N \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation, riemann-zeta

Is it known if for any finite $N$, the partial sum $\sum_1^N \frac{\mu(n)}{n}$ is equal to $0$ or, alternatively, isn’t $0$ for any finite $N$? Where $\mu(n)$ is a Mobius function.[see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function).

We know that the sum converges to $0$ when $N \rightarrow \infty$[see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2433631/proving-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac-mu-nn-0-where-mu-is-the-m%C3%B6biu). But I am wondering about the partial sum for finite $N$.

I have no ideas about how one could prove or disprove it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no $N$ for which the sum is zero.

First, recall that for any integer $N>1$, there is a prime number $p$ such that $N/2<p\le N$.

Let $S_n = \sum_{n=1}^N \mu(n)/n$, and let's consider the value of $p\cdot S_n$ modulo $p$: we can do that as, apart from the term $n=p$, the denominators are all non-zero modulo $p$. This gives us
$$
p\cdot S_n = \sum_{n=1}^N \mu(n)\cdot\frac{p}{n}
\equiv \mu(p) = -1 \pmod p
$$
as the terms for $n\not=p$ all vanish modulo $p$ after multiplication by $p$.